# Distribute data from list into column in panda dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a list `users=['a','b','c','d']`

I have a dataframe X with 100 rows.
I want to populate the `X['users']` with list users, such that

1. distribution is even. In the above example there must be 25 entries of each element
2. the distribution is done in a random way. It shouldn't have a fix pattern of distribution each time I run. `abcdabcd vs aaabbbcccddd vs accbddab` are all valid distributions.

How do I go about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass 25 of each element (`users*25`) into [`np.random.Generator.choice`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.Generator.choice.html#numpy.random.Generator.choice) (or the deprecated [`np.random.choice`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.choice.html)) and set `replace=False`:

```
users = list('abcd')
X = pd.DataFrame()
rng = np.random.default_rng(0)

X['users'] = rng.choice(users*25, size=100, replace=False)
#   users
# 0     d
# 1     d
# 2     b
# 3     a
# ...

X.value_counts()
# users
# a        25
# b        25
# c        25
# d        25
# dtype: int64
```

On additional runs, we get different sampling but always 25 per element:

```
X['users'] = rng.choice(users*25, size=100, replace=False)
#   users
# 0     b
# 1     b
# 2     c
# 3     c
# ...

X.value_counts()
# users
# a        25
# b        25
# c        25
# d        25
# dtype: int64
```

Comment: Followup question: What if the numbers are not exactly divisible. Like 99/4. Will the data be distributed fairly evenly in that case?

Comment: Yeah, you can just lower to `size=99` and it will draw 99 samples without replacement (one element will will have 24 while the others have 25): `rng.choice(users*25, size=99, replace=False)`

Answer (score 2):

So, assuming we have a `df` with 100 rows, I think we can use [`np.repeat`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html) for this.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

X = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros((100, 1)), columns=['users'])

users = ['a','b','c','d'] # users = ['a']
n_users = len(users)
n_rows = X.shape[0]
n_per_user = n_rows // n_users

if n_users == 1:
    users = np.repeat(users, n_rows)
else:
    np.random.shuffle(users)
    users = np.repeat(users, n_per_user)
    if n_rows % n_users != 0:
        n_extra = n_rows % n_users
        extra_users = np.random.choice(users, n_extra, replace=False)
        users = np.concatenate([users, extra_users])

X['users'] = users
```

Comment: Good approach but you need to have a multiple of `len(users)` or assignment as a column will fail

Comment: That is true @mozway, good catch. I sort of made the assumption based on what OP provided.